# Override AdminSite to append custom urls

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I overrode default **AdminSite** class as described in manual, though it's too pure with information about this part over there.
My **gs/admin.py** file:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from gs.views import *

class AdminSiteGs(AdminSite):

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(AdminSiteGs, self).get_urls()

        urls += patterns('',
             url(r'^my_admin_view/$', self.admin_view(my_admin_view))
        )

        return urls

admin_site_gs = AdminSiteGs()
```

*gs* it's my application and project name.

**gs/urls.py file**:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from page import views
from gs.admin import admin_site_gs

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin_site_gs.urls)),
)
```

and I have application named page, where I place **admin.py** file:

```
from gs.admin import admin_site_gs
from page.models import Page, Menu
from django.contrib import admin

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'url', 'page_type')

class MenuAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'code')

admin_site_gs.register(Page, PageAdmin)
admin_site_gs.register(Menu, MenuAdmin)
```

So nothing here is working =( Neither **/admin/my_admin** view ( it returns 404 ), nor main admin page **/admin**. I don't see my models I registered in **page/admin.py** file.

It may sounds fun, but I tried all staff working in 3-4 hours =)) As you might guess I'm completely newbie both in Django and Python... All I want to know now is how to append custom URLs and views to my overriden class of AdminSite?

I removed `autodiscover` method, so now seems Django doesn't see nothing about file **page/admin.py**.

But the first question is more interesting, why I've had 404 error on trying to access the **/admin/my_admin** page ...

PS why my greeting at the beginning has been cutted o_O

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the docs, any URL patterns you define for custom admin views must be occur *before* the admin patterns: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

Try:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(AdminSiteGs, self).get_urls()

    my_urls = patterns('',
        url(r'^my_admin_view/$', self.admin_view(my_admin_view))
    )

    return my_urls + urls
```

You shouldn't need to include these patterns like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin_site_gs.urls)),  # not needed
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Changing the order urls has been glued resolves the problem! But could you please tell me what do you mean the patterns are not needed? If I comment out admin_site_gs.urls how Django know there's my urls placed?

Comment: By overriding `get_urls()`, Django dynamically adds the patterns for you. Since they all begin with `/admin`, you don't have to include them manually in your base urls.py

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to override the default 'add url' in order to redirect to a custom Django admin page when clicking '+Add' button in the admin.
So if I just override get_urls() in the way @Brandon said, it will return a list with a duplicate 'add' url (the custom one and the one retrieved from the super).

```
    def get_urls(self):
        info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name
        urls = super(RetailerAdmin, self).get_urls()
        # We need to remove the original 'add_url' in order to use the custom one.
        urls.remove(urls[1])
        custom_url = [
            url(r'^batch/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.batch_upload_retailers),
                name='%s_%s_add' % info),
        ]
        return custom_url + urls
```

To solve this, I removed the original 'add' url (notice that the 'add' url is always in position 1).